# Topological sorting of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, relations, order-theory

Given this Hasse diagram
[image]

(made from the set $A$: $\{1,2,3,4, 5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60\}$ with the relation **divides**).

> I have to find the topological sorting of the set
>
> $$ \begin{equation} (2,3), (4,6), (2,10), (10,2), (30,30), (2,30)
>  \tag{*} \end{equation} $$

Normally when finding the topological sorting one of the possible sorting could be

$$ 1 \preceq 2 \preceq 3 \preceq 5 \preceq 15 \preceq 10 \preceq 6 \preceq 4 \preceq 12 \preceq 20 \preceq 30 \preceq 60 $$

My question is how and where does (*) come in?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren’t supposed to be working with this set as a subset of the product partial order $A\times A$, with the product partial order? In that case $\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 2,10\rangle$, and $\langle 10,2\rangle$ would be minimal elements, $\langle 30,30\rangle$ would be the maximum element, $\langle 2,3\rangle$ would be below $\langle 4,6\rangle$, and $\langle 2,10\rangle$ would be below $\langle 2,30\rangle$, and you’d have quite a few possibilities for the topological sort.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't quite understand. How would you find the topological sorting then?

Comment: The same way you would with any partial order. Here, for instance, you could put the three minimal elements first in any order, followed by $\langle 4,6\rangle$ and $\langle 2,10\rangle$ in either order, followed by the maximum element. There are other possibilities, though: for instance, $\langle 4,6\rangle$ has to come after $\langle 2,3\rangle$, but it need not come after the other two minimal elements. The only real requirements are that $\langle 30,30\rangle$ be last, that $\langle 2,3\rangle$ precede $\langle 4,6\rangle$, and that $\langle 2,10\rangle$ preceded $\langle 2,30\rangle$. ...

Comment: ... Of course this is all on the assumption that you’re supposed to be looking at this in terms of the product partial order.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Reading the question again, you are right about it being the subset of the product partial order. However, I can't seem to find anything about finding the topological sorting in my book or on the internet in this case. I don't understand how to use the Hasse diagram to find the sorting. Do I write the sets $(4,6), (2,10)...$ in the diagram somehow?

Comment: Do you see how to make the Hasse diagram for this six-element partial order?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can't seem to find a way, no.

Comment: I’ve posted an answer with the Hasse diagram; see if that’s enough to let you finish the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the Hasse diagram of your partial order: $\langle a,b\rangle\preceq\langle c,d\rangle$ if and only if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid d$.

```
                         <30,30>  
                        /   |   \  
                       /    |    \  
                   <4,6>    |    <2,30>  
                      |     |     |  
                      |     |     |  
                   <2,3>  <10,2> <2,10>
```

Can you work from it to get a topological sort?

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Then one possible topological sorting could be
$(2,3) \preceq (10,2) \preceq (2,10) \preceq (4,6) \preceq (2,30) \preceq (30,30)$.

Comment: @Stranqer95: Yes, that works fine.